# WebDriverIO Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I haven't found any resources on how to properly implement drag and drop in wdio v 7. It seems like the built in drag and drop function in the API doesn't work for Chrome. I'm curious if anyone has any work arounds for v7 of wdio as the other resources online are for earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

I read the Drag and Drop like this (I write tests for the coffeescript ):

```
  # @coords_canvas - coordinates of the canvas on the screen
  mousedown_with_canvas: (x, y) ->
    # coordinates relative to the center of the canvas 
    x = x + @coords_canvas.left + @sizes_of_canvas.width / 2
    y = y + @coords_canvas.top + @sizes_of_canvas.height / 2
    browser.executeScript('e = new Event("mousedown");'+
    'e.clientX = arguments[0];'+
    'e.clientY = arguments[1];'+
    'e.altKey = false;'+
    'e.button = 0;'+
    'e.buttons = 1;'+
    'e.ctrlKey = false;'+
    'e.metaKey = false;'+
    'e.shiftKey = false;'+
    'window.document.querySelector("div.myDiagramDiv canvas").dispatchEvent(e);',
    [x, y, @max_canva])

  mousemove_with_canvas: (x, y) ->
    # coordinates relative to the center of the canvas 
    x = x + @coords_canvas.left + @sizes_of_canvas.width / 2
    y = y + @coords_canvas.top + @sizes_of_canvas.height / 2
    browser.executeScript('e = new Event("mousemove");'+
    'e.clientX = arguments[0];'+
    'e.clientY = arguments[1];'+
    'e.altKey = false;'+
    'e.button = 0;'+
    'e.buttons = 1;'+
    'e.ctrlKey = false;'+
    'e.metaKey = false;'+
    'e.shiftKey = false;'+
    'window.document.querySelector("div.myDiagramDiv canvas").dispatchEvent(e);',
    [x, y, @max_canva])

  mouseup_with_canvas: (x, y) ->
    # coordinates relative to the center of the canvas 
    x = x + @coords_canvas.left + @sizes_of_canvas.width / 2
    y = y + @coords_canvas.top + @sizes_of_canvas.height / 2
    browser.executeScript('e = new Event("mouseup");'+
    'e.clientX = arguments[0];'+
    'e.clientY = arguments[1];'+
    'e.altKey = false;'+
    'e.button = 0;'+
    'e.buttons = 1;'+
    'e.ctrlKey = false;'+
    'e.metaKey = false;'+
    'e.shiftKey = false;'+
    'window.document.querySelector("div.myDiagramDiv canvas").dispatchEvent(e);',
    [x, y, @max_canva])

  drag_and_drop: (point_1, point_2,
      status_of_select_elems = false) ->
    @mousedown_with_canvas(
      point_1.x,
      point_1.y
    )
    if status_of_select_elems
      browser.pause(1000)
    @mousemove_with_canvas(
      point_2.x,
      point_2.y
    )
    @mouseup_with_canvas(
      point_2.x,
      point_2.y
    )
```

Please let me know if I was able to resolve your issue.